# cakephp disable routing for specific URLs

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have a CakePHP 1.3.10 app which I'm trying to make it do the following:

I want to embed a mp3 file in some views, using Google's reader flash audio player. If I put the mp3 file in the webroot directory of my app, there's no problem. However, I would like to have those files in a directory called **AUDIO** at the same level of my app directory. Like:

```
[public_html]
    [app]
    [cake]
    [AUDIO]
    ...
```

The problem is that if I put my mp3 files there, when I link to them from my view, Cake looks for the controller **audio**, which doesn't exist, instead of just linking my file. I believe this has something to do with routing, so I was wondering if I can disable automatic routing for a specific folder (**audio in this case).

I want to do this in this way because in the future I might have to access those mp3 from other websites, so I don't want to put them deep into cake's directory system.

Thanks so much in advance for any tips!

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to create the AUDIO directory inside the webroot directory? Then you can link them with `http://www.mysite.com/AUDIO/file.mp3`

Comment: well, the main reason is because it would actually go inside the webroot directory of a plugin. This makes that the AUDIO directory would be located very deep inside the application folder. It's not a big deal, but I work with other people who don't know much about CakePHP and I like to make things as simple as possible. But if there's no alternative, I'll just put them there

Comment: if you want the link to work for your views, you could write the link as `<?=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];?>/AUDIO/file.mp3` but I don't think you'd be able to link to the file from a direct URL. Actually I'm not sure how that would work from a plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files that should be directly served by the web server without going through Cake should be put in the `/app/webroot` directory. You can create such a `/webroot` directory in plugins as well (see [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1117/Plugin-assets)), which technically will use routing, but behaves the same as the general webroot directory.

If you place them anywhere else you're going against Cake conventions, which I wouldn't recommend. Not because it's not possible, you're just making your life harder than it needs to be. You can edit the `/app/webroot/.htaccess` file to rewrite certain URLs to wherever you stored your files or use Media Views (as pointed out by @Ivo) if you really want to do this.

Comment: Actually, afaik, media views were created for just such a purpose; if you want to be able to selectively serve files, but keep them out of /webroot/ so that they're not freely accessible. Media views are part of Cake's conventions, so you can't be going against them by using them :P

Comment: @Ivo Sure, but it seems the OP wants to *freely* offer these files, but not put them in the webroot. I haven't seen anything about selectively allowing downloads in the question. That's against conventions. :P

Comment: Cool thank you! I ended up putting them into the plugin webroot

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP won't be able to automatically find files in folders that it doesn't know about.

I'd suggest using [Media Views](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1094/Media-Views) to serve files from a custom directory.

If you want them to be freely downloadable, you can do this using MediaView also, or put them in a custom folder inside webroot. You'll need to include that folder in paths etc, though.